# Ignore bundled .d.ts and use external declarations

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the [validate.js](http://validatejs.org/) library, which includes its own TypeScript declaration file.

Unfortunately it's not a very good typing of the library, and there's [a much better one](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/validate.js/index.d.ts) in DefinitelyTyped. I installed the `@types/validate.js` NPM package, but TypeScript isn't using it, and is instead using the declarations bundled directly with the library.

Is there any way to make the compiler use the better declarations I have available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use declarations for `validate.js` from DefinitelyTyped alone because there is not a single top-level `export` in it - they just declare some interfaces inside `ValidateJS` namespace.

And you can't use bundled declarations for `validate.js`, at least for node (`module=commonjs`), because they use default export instead of `export =`.

So you have to provide your own declarations in order to import `validate.js` properly:

create file **validate.d.ts**:

```
declare var validate: (attributes: any, constraints: any, options?: any) => any;
export = validate;
```

And tell typescript to use it instead of the one in `node_modules` using [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "validate.js":  ["./validate.d.ts"]
    }
  }
```

(Note that you must have `baseUrl` if you have `paths`, so set `"baseUrl" : "."` if you don't have it set to something else already)

Then you can use it like this (`ValidateJS.Constraints` and others are available immediately as soon as you `npm install @types/validate.js`):

```
import validate = require('validate.js');


let constraints: ValidateJS.Constraints = {
    'foo': {presence: true}
};

let e = validate({}, constraints);

console.dir(e);
```

output:

```
{ foo: [ 'Foo can\'t be blank' ] }
```

Comment: ah! yeah now that you mention it the DefinitelyTyped [tests for validate.js](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/validate.js/validate.js-tests.ts#L1-L3) use a global namespace import. fun fun fun. but tsconfig `paths` works! much obliged :)