# Exclude/overwrite npm-provided typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've got an npm package with badly written, out of date typings. I've written my own typings and now I'm wondering if I can somehow exclude the original typings from the npm package. It's not a simple extension of interfaces, the originals are basically garbage at this point.

Using the exclude list in tsconfig.json does not work for this purpose of course, since it still loads files from node_modules even if you exclude that folder.

Comment: You can try to use [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in `tsconfig.json` to override typings for any module as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41559327/43848)

Comment: That's the correct answer. I didn't find that question using google, because I tried all sorts of wordings, but apparently not that one.

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get the desired behavior with the paths option in the tsConfig
It could look something like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
       ...
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "src/*",
                "declarations/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

With this config typescript looks for modules in src (there should be all the app source) and also in declarations, in the declarations folder I usually place my extra needed declarations.

To override the typings of a node module there are two options:

1. place a folder named like the module inside the declarations folder, containing a file called index.d.ts for the typings
2. place a declaration file, named like the module, inside the declarations folder

As a working example you can take a look at this repo https://github.com/kaoDev/react-ts-sample

An important hint by [Bernhard Koenig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217387/bernhard-koenig):

> The order of the paths matters. I had to put the path with my overrides before the path with the original type definitions so my overrides get picked up first. – Bernhard Koenig

Comment: Not working for nats-hemera npm module, could you check?

Comment: The order of the paths matters. I had to put the path with my overrides before the path with the original type definitions so my overrides get picked up first.

Comment: Careful with two things, with paths overriding: 1) The right-hand "target" for the path redirect is _relative to the baseUrl_. If set wrong, it may silently fail (or work for some but not others depending on the way the d.ts file was referenced). 2) Even if set correctly, some cases require that you add an empty `declare module "my-module";` declaration somewhere in your project `*.d.ts` files. Example requiring both fixes above: `mst-decorators@2.1.1` (that exact version)

Answer (score 29):

Create `node_modules` folder under your `src`, then put typings of module(s) you want to overwrite inside:

```
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
│
└── src
    ├── index.ts
    ├── ... your codes ...
    │
    └── node_modules
        └── <module-to-be-overwritten>
            └── index.d.ts
```

No need to modify `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json.

Read *How TypeScript resolves modules* section in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html.

Comment: This doesn't work for every case -- for example, `mst-decorators@2.1.1` (that exact version) -- but works for most. I prefer the [paths approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41641001/2441655) more though, as it works for every case, and doesn't require creating fake/override directories. (I'd rather add one line to `tsconfig.json` than create two new folders and a file that are mere stubs -- to each their own, though)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `patch-package` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) for this.

Here's the technical procedure:

1. Delete the `index.d.ts` file located in `node_modules/{library}/index.d.ts`.
2. Install `patch-package` by running `npm i patch-package`.
3. In your `package.json` file, add the following script under the "scripts" section:

```json
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

4. Run the following command to create a patch for the package you want to modify:

```bash
npx patch-package package-name
```

This approach allows you to make specific modifications to a package's code and maintain those changes using `patch-package`.