# Exclude or Overwrite existing type definition file

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to overwrite an existing library definition file with my own to include some fixes. Here's the directory structure:

```
node_modules/
  preact/
    dist/
      preact.d.ts <-- this file is wrong, I'd like to use my own
types/
  preact.d.ts <-- use this file instead
```

Is there anyway to either completely overwrite the one that comes with preact or exclude that file from being picked up? Right now it's showing `Duplicate identifier`'s all over the place.

If it helps, here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5",
            "es6",
            "es7"
        ],
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "types/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/preact/dist/preact.d.ts"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [
            "types/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Woops! Looks like I found the answer here: [Exclude/overwrite npm-provided typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings?rq=1)

`paths` should be under `compilerOptions`, not top-level.