# How can I overwrite a node_module bad typing in Angular-CLI project?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I have a bad node_module (angularfire2) that is not updated with the newer typings found in another node_module (@firebase).

I'm trying to get tsconfig.json to help me set a path alias for it so that it will be rerouted to resolve to a tweaked file written in src instead of the incompatible typing file in @firebase's node_modules as a temporary fix.

I know that I can downgrade the (@firebase) node_module so that it will be compatible. However this question isn't about getting it to work. I just want to figure out how to be able to overwrite node_module bad typings.

I'm using Angular's cli project and hope I don't need to eject webpack to control it.

I've learned from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322788/how-to-overwrite-incorrect-typescript-type-definition-installed-via-types-packa?rq=1) that I overwrite typings placed in the @types folder.

However I'm still having trouble overwriting typings with an index.d.ts in a node_module itself.

E.g. (from angularfire2)

```
import { FirebaseApp as FBApp } from '@firebase/app-types';
```

I would like to create an alias for `@firebase/app-types` in my tsconfig.json so that angularfire2 will look in `src/types-overwrite/@firebase/app-types`.

I have the following tsconfig.json but it still won't do the aliasing correctly and will still resolve to the incompatible node_module's typing file instead of the one in src.

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types-overwrite"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@firebase/app-types": ["src/types-overwrite/@firebase/app-types"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/angularfire2",
  ]
}
```

How can overwrite index.d.ts typing files in a node_module in the Angular-CLI project or how can I get my tsconfig.json to work?

### update:

I added a repository to showcase the problem:

- '@firebase/app-types' has extra typings for logging purposes (from_node_modules or from_src) (so node_modules are already included in repository)

URL: https://github.com/Jonathan002/resolve-typing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found my answer over at this post:

[Exclude/overwrite npm-provided typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings)

Added:

- baseUrl - needed for paths resolving to work
- paths
- includes (updated)

to my tsconfig.json while copying the package typing codes and referring to it in the declarations folder:

- declarations/package-name.d.ts

tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "src/*", 
        "declarations/*",
      ]
    },
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "declarations/**/*.d.ts"],
}
```