# Handling wrong package typings

Tags: typescript

I am using a JavaScript library which is published via NPM along with TypeScript typings. Unfortunately these typings are often wrong. PullRequests take ages to be merged and therefore I am looking for a better option how I can fix the typings on my local project.

I tried to create my own types in `/src/types/package-name.d.ts` and I added

```
"paths": {
    "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
    ]
},
```

to my tsconfig.json. Unfortunately it seems the typings inside of the package are still prefered and I can not overwrite them.

**Example code:**

node_modules/package/index.d.ts:

```
declare module 'discord.js-commando' {
  export class XY {
    addZ(): number; // WRONG! <-- it should be number | string
  }
}
```

My /src/types/package-fix.d.ts:

```
declare module 'discord.js-commando' {
  export class XY {
    addZ(): number | string; // Right! <-- Still does not work :(
  }
}
```

**My question:**

How can I fix package type definitions which are shipped along with the package?

Comment: You can get it from PR branch and/or fork it (that's what we do if PR takes a long time). Or you can always delete index.d.ts in postinstall.

Comment: @estus Is there a way to ignore the shipped typings? Then I could copy and maintain them in my own repository's typings folder.

Comment: To my knowledge, no, that's why I suggested these options.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794250/94148