# Working around a bad index.d.ts file provided by npm package

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I recently encountered an npm package that wasn't written in TypeScript but did provide its own `index.d.ts` file. Unfortunately, these types were inaccurate and contributed by someone who wasn't maintaining the package. When I add a `/// <reference...` directive to point to my fixed types, VS Code seems unsure of what to do and informs me that there are two type definitions for the given objects. I can't move on while this is unresolved. What's my move here to get working other than editing the file in `node_modules` on my machine?

If these types were provided by DefinitelyTyped, this would be easy: I'd just remove the bad ones, submit a PR with my changes, use my local version in the meantime. Since this `index.d.ts` is part of the library itself, is my only option to clone the whole repo, work from that, submit a PR when I'm ready, hope they merge and release a new version quickly? That doesn't seem right. Is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore a specific index.d.ts file in `node_modules` so mine is the only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings/50794250#50794250), linked in the comment by @AlesD on the other answer, did the trick perfectly. In `src`, create `node_modules/problem-library/index.d.ts` and place updated type definitions there. They will override those provided by the library.

Your .gitignore is likely to ignore your file, which is no good. You can fix 
that by modifying your .gitignore

```
node_modules/
!src/node_modules/
```

The first is your existing exclusion of the folder, the second adds a pattern that will negate it for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Add `skipLibCheck: true` in the `compilerOptions` in the `tsconfig.json` file.
This disables the type checking for all *.d.ts files.

The flag is described in the [compiler options documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Another option if you are sure your code is correct is to ignore the errors by using `// @ts-ignore` comments on the lines where you get errors.

Here is also a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings) to a similar post that offers also two possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you but it's not that there are type errors in the file, they just weren't maintained so they're completely inaccurate. Wrong arguments, missing functions/methods, etc,...

Comment: I understand. Still the code should compile if you add this setting. The type checking means checking your code against the type definitions not the definition file. I also updated the answer with another option and a link to a simmilar post that offers other workarounds.

Comment: The comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794250/2105069 worked wonderfully. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `patch-package` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) for this.

Here's the technical procedure:

1. Delete the `index.d.ts` file located in `node_modules/{package-name}/index.d.ts`.
2. Install `patch-package` by running `npm i patch-package`.
3. In your `package.json` file, add the following script under the "scripts" section:

```json
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

4. Run the following command to create a patch for the package you want to modify:

```bash
npx patch-package package-name
```

This approach allows you to make specific modifications to a package's code and maintain those changes using `patch-package`.