# Bootstrap-vue not compiling : Multiple "Type X is not assignable to type Y"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am currently trying to solve an issue that I am facing relating `bootstrap-vue`. More precisely, it seems that there is a problem with bootstrap-vue itself during the build of my code : However, I am quite a beginner in Typescript/Vue, and thus I'm not really sure about that itself.

When I try to compile my code, I encounted the following message :

```
ERROR in [MY PROJECT PATH]/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.d.ts
149:20 Interface 'Table' incorrectly extends interface 'Vue'.
  Types of property 'fields' are incompatible.
    Type 'TableFieldObject | (string | ({ key: string; } & TableField))[]'
is not assignable to type 'FieldFlagsBag'.
      Type 'TableFieldObject' is not assignable to type 'FieldFlagsBag'.
        Index signatures are incompatible.
          Type 'TableField' is not assignable to type 'FieldFlags'.
            Property 'untouched' is missing in type 'TableField'.
    147 |   }
    148 |   export interface Progress extends Vue {}
  > 149 |   export interface Table extends Vue {
        |                    ^
    150 |     refresh: () => void
    151 |     fields?: TableFieldObject | TableFieldArray
    152 |   }
```

I tried to search on Google if a similar issue has already been reported, but couldn't find anything.

I tried uninstalling and installing bootstrap-vue again, but the error still exists ; I tried uninstalling and installing my whole project again, but the error still exists ; And I tried reverting my code to the state it was yesterday (When I didn't had this error), but once again, the problem kept appearing.

Once again, I am rather new on Typescript and Vue. It seems to me that the problem isn't coming from me, but as far as it goes with programming, it probably is my fault somewhere. However, I have no idea where, and thus, no idea what part of code to show.

Could someone please help me fix this issue, explaining me why it is happening / how to prevent it from happening in the future ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Update : I got a friend to try with my code, and he encountered no problem at all : It seems that this is a local-specific problem. I also tried a few more things (Installing a version of bootstrap-vue oldest than 2.0.0-rc.18, or cleaning the npm cache), but nothing changed.

Comment: I got the same problem.  Is there any fix that anyone has found?  My project just started leaving off labels on fields and making them all fieldsets after this errror.

Comment: I have the same issue, and so do some of my colleagues. It does seem environment related. Removing the line `fields?: TableFieldObject | TableFieldArray` from the offending `node-modules/bootstrap-vue` file will get you past the error. I still haven't figured out root cause yet though.

Comment: Also, just to mention it, I have my project set up on a mac with no issues. Setting up the same project from scratch on a Win10 machine encountered this issue right away.

Comment: @Dpeif After searching around some more, the only way to solve this that I could find was to change the version of packages. I was using bootstrap-vue 2.0.0-rc.18, and the only way to solve this that I found was to go back all the way to 2.0.0-rc.11 (And adapt my code accordingly). Maybe there are better ways to solve this, but I couldn't find any, sorry about that ^^

Comment: Also tagging @frankie4fingers since I guess it can be considered a somewhat solution

Comment: I solved it temporarily by just commenting out the line that @Dpeif suggested for now.  I need updates from the newer version so I cannot downgrade :(

Comment: @frankie4fingers Just curious, have you noticed any ill effects from commenting that line out? I have not, just FTR. Haven't had time to dig into the Bootstrap-Vue code to compare that line to legacy builds, but my table component (and their fields) all still work.

Comment: @Dpeif no I didn't notice any issues with it commented out but I have a team of 15 people working on this and having them modify node-modules stuff isn't a good idea.

Comment: I did put in an issue on the Bootstrap Vue website about this.  No feedback so far.

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3099

Comment: @Dpeif are you guys using veevalidate for your validations?  We are and it looks like it is causing the conflict actually.

Comment: @frankie4fingers Yes, my team is, and thanks for the heads up. I've saved this post and will add any new info I come across.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794250/3499604

In my case `vee-validate` adds the `fields` property to `Vue`. It is not problem since it is possible to reconfigure `vee-validate` to use other name for such property. But the typings stills conflicting.

To override `vee-validate` typings:

create `<your_project>/src/node_modules/vee-validate` and copy here files from `<your_project>/node_modules/vee-validate/types`,

...so you will have `<your_project>/src/node_modules/vee-validate/vue.d.ts` which you able to edit...

in my case, I just renamed `fields` => `vFields` (consider my `fieldsBagName` option of `vee-validate`).