# Override typings of node_modules package with declare namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

### Context

Recently types for jest at DefinitelyTyped has been updated changing an interface from `Matchers<R>` to `Matchers<R,T>`, but jest-extended has it own types and those has not been updated yet causing TypeScript to fail with:

```
error TS2428: All declarations of 'Matchers' must have identical type parameters.
```

There is a [PR](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended/pull/235) but the repo hasn't had much activity so maybe it takes a while to get merged.

I want to override its types in my project but following recommendations like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322788/how-to-overwrite-incorrect-typescript-type-definition-installed-via-types-packa) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings) does not work properly. Using `paths` in tsconfig doesn't seem right in this case since jest-extended is not meant to be imported every time, instead it augments the global jest declarations. The file start with

```
/// <reference types="jest" />

declare namespace jest {
```

and have no `import` or `export`.

### What I want

I want to override the types of the `jest-extended` package and provide my own, without turning on `skipLibCheck` and get rid off the error.

### What I tried

I am using `typeRoots` like this:

```
{
   // ...
   "typeRoots": ["./types/overrides", "node_modules/@types"],
}
```

I have the file `types/overrides/jest-extended/index.d.ts` with a modified copy of jest-extended  declarations. I think the file is being read by TS since I see the effect of some changes (for instance I changed the return type of `toReject(): R` to `toReject(): Promise<R>` and TSLint is now happy about `await-promise`).

But... I still see the error since the file `node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts` is still loaded by TypeScript. I thought the order of directories in `typeRoots` would make TS catch only my own file. I cannot uninstall the types with npm since they're not in a different package.

**How do I override the types completely inside my project?**

**Is this a properly use of `typeRoots`?**

**How to deal with this issues in a more general way? (Beyond just jest-extended)**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly specify the order of @types directories in typeRoots option. For example, if you have folders «node_modules/@types» and «src/@types», the first should be «src/@types» and specify exclude.

```
"typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"], 
"exclude": ["node_modules/jest-extended/types/*"]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sadly I cannot make this work this way either. I'll try to create a reproduction repo later on, maybe I'm misinterpreting something.