# Is it possible to force typescript to use types from DefinitelyTyped instead of native lib types?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, definitelytyped

I'm trying to migrate to sequelize v5 which now has built-in typescript types. I'm not exactly happy how said types are written: data-related methods (find/create/update/etc) use "object" as  data values type. Types from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) are written using generics and dont have such drawback.

The problem is now typescript compiler detects built-in types from sequelize and ignores DefinitelyTyped types. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Did you try to add a reference in your file ? Like `/// <reference types="mylib" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings) provides a solution:

In your .tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
       "*": [
         "types/*", // locally defined types
         "node_modules/@types/*" // DefinitelyTyped typings for applicable packages
       ]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This means the compiler will first look in your local `/types` folder, and then in `node_modules/@types/`, before resorting to the lib-defined typings.