# How to type a standalone object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
AWSMock.mock("SQS", "receiveMessage", {
    Messages: [
        {
            MessageId: "abcd",
            Body: "sample body",
        },
    ],
});
```

**In the example above, how to type the object as a `ReceiveMessageResult` instance?**

I cannot type the `AWSMock.mock()` method as this is a generic method in a 3rd party mocking library.

️ This doesn't work, as it wouldn't catch any type error (for example any missing field would not trigger an error):

```
AWSMock.mock("SQS", "receiveMessage", {
    Messages: [
        {
            MessageId: "abcd",
            Body: "sample body",
        },
    ],
} as ReceiveMessageResult);
```

️ This could work, but I don't want to go through an extra variable:

```
const response: ReceiveMessageResult = {
    Messages: [
        {
            MessageId: "abcd",
            Body: "sample body",
        },
    ],
};
AWSMock.mock("SQS", "receiveMessage", response);
```

Is there any way to type a object on the fly?

Comment: I sadly think that your third solution is the only way to do this.

Comment: Which ts version are you on? I've tried a similar code to the one that didn't work for you and it had autocompletion. Also you might try the old assertion: `..."receiveMessage", <ReceiveMessageResult>{ Messages: [...`

Comment: @EcksDy Right, indeed I do get autocompletion but the type is not validated. What I mean is that if I don't respect the interface, then TypeScript will not show any error.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Then assertion is not the tool for the job. Assertion is telling TS to disregard anything it knows about the target and accept your assertion as the truth. By that definition it cannot show you any error, since you overrode any possible errors with an assertion statement. It won't even look for discrepancies between the type and the actual object. Your last example works because it's not assertion. You're making a variable `response` that can receive only objects that fit `ReceiveMessageResult`. If you do `const response: ReceiveMessageResult = 3;` that would be an error.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli doing `const response: ReceiveMessageResult = 3 as ReceiveMessageResult;` will not raise a compilation error though, since you'd be overriding what ts knows about 3(number) and marking it `as ReceiveMessageResult`. You'd get a "ts(2352)" error, telling you to convert to unknown first and then to ReceiveMessageResult, but it would still compile.

Comment: @EcksDy yes, so we agree right? This is not a good solution. I'm not sure if I'm missing something from your comments.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Yeah, unfortunately I cannot think of any other solution than the one you attempted in the question.   Last suggestion is to check if the library you're using accepts type parameters? Something like `AWSMock.mock<ReceiveMessageResult>(...,...,/*{ReceiveMessageResult}*/)`.

Comment: Please see this PR https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/pull/242, I believe they should reorder function overloads.

Comment: My question isn't about aws-mock specifically. This was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It isn't possible.**

My question was about doing this in TypeScript *without workarounds* (which I already have). All other questions provide new and different workarounds.

I believe these other answers are still useful (feel free to read them), but I want to mark a clear answer to those facing the same problem as me: there is no native solution. It just cannot be done without workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options:

1. Create a PR in the target project with better typing. But I see that there is already [a PR from 2019](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/pull/180) and it is not merged.
2. Do not use poorly maintained 3rd party libraries.
3. Override typings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41641001/1784230). But then you have to maintain it yourself.
4. Use a variable as you have suggested (which might be the most straightforward option imho)
5. Create a wrapper function:

```js
function t<T>(input: T): T {
  return input;
}

interface Book {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

function log(input: any): any {
  console.log(input);
}

log({title: 'Galaxy Guide'} as Book); // Does not complain
log(t<Book>({title: 'Galaxy Guide'})); // Complains that id is missing
```

6. Create an overloading function and use it everywhere:

```js
function myAwsMock<T>(service: string, method: string, replace: T): void {
  AWSMock.mock(service, method, replace);
}
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are irrelevant, I have the same problem with sinon. What do you mean by 3? Is it different from 5?

I think we are heading to an answer which is "It's not possible".

Comment: I have edited my answer. 1 is relevant if you want to go with 3. You can basically copy the typings from there. I have never worked with Sinon, but their typings look definitely way better than this library.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I believe overloads for `mock` functions should be reordered, but it is not directly related to our problem.
I made a [PR](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/pull/242)

In order to make it work, you should write your own custom declaration of `aws-sdk-mock` module.

1. Create `typings.d.ts` file in your root folder.
2. Paste this code into `typings.d.ts`

```js
declare module 'aws-sdk-mock' {
    function mock<T>(service: "SQS", method: "receiveMessage", replace: T): void;
}
```

It is important to add generic `T`, because it is more specific than `any` in built in declaration.

3. Then you should explicitly use generic parameter:

```js
import AWSMock from 'aws-sdk-mock';

type Message = {
    MessageId: string;
    Body: string;
}

type ReceiveMessageResult = {
    Messages: Message[],
}

AWSMock.mock<ReceiveMessageResult>("SQS", "receiveMessage", {
    Messages: [
        {
            MessageId: "abcd",
            Body: "sample body",
            x: 1 // expected error
        },
    ],
});
```

Voila, it works.

I have tried to make it work without explicit generic parameter, but because there is `any` type for third argument in built in types, it is impossible to use more specific type after `any`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question is generic. It isn't related to aws-mock, and it actually happens in different places where introducing custom types isn't an option, or isn't something I want to do every time.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli but you can write your own custom overloads for any third party library in the same way

Comment: Yeah, but if I'm going through all that trouble then I might as well create a useless variable. My goal was to avoid having to do a workaround.

Comment: I would not say that it is a workaround, this is just how TS works, but sure no problem.