# Enforcing specific return type with Express JSON response

Tags: typescript, express

We are developing an API using Express and Typescript that always responds to requests with JSON in a specific format. We would like to enforce this response format for all of our endpoints.

Our thoughts were to overwrite the `json()` method type in the `Response` object of Express handlers, but we stumbled upon an issue here. We haven't found a clear way on how to override this one specific method. We were able to either:

- Completely overwrite all Express types. But this is far from ideal because this means we'd need to re-declare ALL types, not just the one function signature. We used [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings) for this (declaring modules).
- Extend the `Request` interface with new types using namespaces. We found that this method allows extending types, but were not able to overwrite exisiting ones.

**Thus:**

- Is overwriting a type for one specific function possible?
- If not, is there another way to enforce a specific type when using the `Response.json()` function?

Comment: It sounds like what you want here is _middleware_, e.g. one that checks the shape of the payload after the handler has asked the server to respond (maybe something like `router.get("/path", correctResponseType, (req, res) => { /* ... */ });`) - this would allow actual runtime checking. Or a new method on `req`, e.g. `req.typedJson<Type>(/* ... */);`, rather than trying to override the existing type but only in certain places.

Comment: This is definitely an option! But I'd prefer doing it with Typescript types as this allows us to verify the format as we are writing our code. Using middleware, issues would only become apparent after sending the actual requests.

Comment: Aha, adding a completely separate method in addition to the `json` method seems like a viable and straightforward solution! How could one go about extending the existing `Response` object? Simply extending the type isn't going to work for this.